# Material UI: How to show Modal one time on a item in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a array of objects. I want to show `Modal` on `Remove` button click.

But when I click on `Remove` button the modal is showing the no. of objects times the array. That is, if there are 2 objects in array, it showing 2 times. And if it is 5 objects, then it will show 5 times.

This is my code:

```
const [importedgroups, setimportedgroups] = React.useState(groups.groupsList);
const [removeImportGroup, setremoveImportGroup] = React.useState(false);
const handleRemoveDownGroup = () => {
  setremoveImportGroup(false);
};
const removeGroups = (index) => {
  const removeg = [...importedgroups];
  removeg.splice(index, 1);
  setimportedgroups(removeg);
};
{
  importedgroups.map((row, index) => (
    <TableRow key={row.name}>
      <TableCell>{row.groupName}</TableCell>

      <TableCell>
        <Button
          href="#text-buttons"
          color="primary"
          disableRipple
          onClick={() => setremoveImportGroup(true)}
        >
          <div>
            <RemoveCircleOutlineIcon/>{" "}
            Remove
          </div>
        </Button>
        <Modal
          className="modal__style"
          open={removeImportGroup}
          onClose={handleRemoveDownGroup}
          closeAfterTransition
          BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
          BackdropProps={{
            timeout: 500,
          }}
        >
          <Fade in={removeImportGroup}>
            <div className="modal__paper">
              <h3>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remove
              </h3>

              <p >
                Are you sure you remove this group permanently?
              </p>

              <form>
                <Button
                  variant="outlined"
                  disableRipple
                  
                  onClick={handleRemoveDownGroup}
                >
                  Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  disableRipple
                  onClick={() => removeGroups(index)}
                >
                  Continue
                </Button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </Fade>
        </Modal>
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  ));
}
```

JSON code:

```
{
  "groupsList": [
    {
      "groupId": 1,
      "groupName": "abc",
      "groupDistinguishName": ""
    },
    {
      "groupId": 2,
      "groupName": "cde",
      "groupDistinguishName": ""
    }
    ]
}
```

How to show `Modal` on `Remove` button click one at a time on item and remove it using index?

Answer (score 0):

Your modal can't stay inside the map functional, your need create a const when the button click is gona set to open the modal like this

```
const MyFunctional = () =>{
    const MyOject = [
        {ID: 1,Group: 'Group1'},
        {ID: 2,Group: 'Garoup2'},
    ]
    const [itemSelected, setSelected] = useState([])
    const [openModal, setModalOpen] = useState(false)
    const openModal = (item) =>{
        const Item = MyObject.filter((obj) => obj.ID === item)
        setSelected(Item)
        setModalOpen(true)
    }
    return(
        <div>
            {MyObject.map((obj) =>(
                <li key = {ID}>
                    <ul>{obj.ID}</ul>
                    <ul>{obj.Group}</ul>
                    <button onClick = {() => openModal(obj.ID)}>Delete</button>
                </li>
            ))}
            <Modal
                open = {openModal}       
            >
                {itemSelected.map((obj) =>(
                    <li key = {obj.ID}>  
                        <ul>{obj.Group}</ul>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This should solve your problem with modal, this code will show the item inside the modal when the item clicked

Comment: It is working fine. But there is one issue i.e., whenever I select the item, it shows the item which is 1 item before the selected item. And along with this the `itemSelected` sometimes gets automatically emptied even after clicking on the item.

Comment: i tested in my local machine and works fine, you can send more details?

Comment: when I select 2nd item then it shows 1st item, and when I refresh the page then it shows 2nd item in the modal. The selected item is working fine. But the modal is not showing the correct time at a time.